# Poor performance on MySQL 5.7 on joined tables ( scanning wrong table ?)

Tags: mysql, index, join

I have a joined table (News, Publishers) with indexing. The query is working fine on MySQL 5.5.
After I upgrading one of the server to MySQL 5.7, I start noticing high load, high CPU, and slow query.
A query taking almost 0.00 seconds (5.5) took 2 to 5 seconds in MySQL 5.7

Query:

```
SELECT   news.id FROM news ,publishers
WHERE    news.publisher_id=publishers.id
AND      publishers.language='en'
ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 10;
```

I tried to figure what happen with EXPLAIN, and here is my finding:

```
MySQL 5.5
+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+----------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys    | key            | key_len | ref                             | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+----------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | news       | index  | idx_publisher_id | idx_date_added | 9       | NULL                            |   10 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | publishers | eq_ref | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY        | 8       | klsescre_klse.news.publisher_id |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+----------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+-------------+

MySQL 5.7
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref                         | rows | filtered | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | publishers | NULL       | index | PRIMARY          | NULL             | 277     | NULL                        |   47 |    10.00 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | news       | NULL       | ref   | idx_publisher_id | idx_publisher_id | 8       | klsescre_klse.publishers.id | 4962 |   100.00 | NULL                                                      |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

My guess is in 5.7, MySQL scan the PUBLISHERS table before NEWS, thus not making use of INDEX of I created for NEWS, making the query much slower.

Can anyone help me with this? How can I make MySQL 5.7 scan the table like 5.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Damned if you do, damned if you don't.  The Optimizer has two choices -- filter on language *in one table* first, or scan on date *in the other table* first.

If the recent articles are in English, then using the date is better.  If you ask for some language with few articles, the other index is better.

Meanwhile, the Optimizer does not have the smarts to look in two different directions at once to decide which is better.

I would argue that the schema is not 'correct'.  Can't a publisher provide news in multiple languages?  If so, `language` should be in `news`, not in `publishers`.  If you make than change, then `INDEX(language, date_added)` would become an better index.

I have addressed the general [*"news" list problem*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/lists) with the addition *and maintenance* of a separate table.